# Simplifying $\|\Sigma^{-1}_{YY}\Sigma_{YX}W\Sigma_{YX}\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}\|_F<0.5\ \ \forall W s.t. \|W\|_F=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, linear-transformations

I have random variable $(X,Y)$ with mean $(0, 0)$ covariance matrix

$$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\Sigma_{XX} & \Sigma_{XY}\\
\Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_{YY}
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

My application requires that the following is true for all matrices $W$ with $\|W\|_F=1$, the Frobenius norm

$$\|\Sigma^{-1}_{YY}\Sigma_{YX}W\Sigma_{YX}\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}\|_F<\frac{1}{2}$$

I'm able to compute largest eigenvalue of a related matrix below (this is known as the canonical correlation between $X$ and $Y$). Is there a good bound on $c$ (or another easy-to-interpret quantity) which makes condition above true?

$$c=\rho(\Sigma_{YX}\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1})$$